# Using aggregate to find a function (mean) for "all other"

Tags: r, aggregate

I've been playing around with `aggregate` and `plyr` -- and searched SO -- but can't seem figure this out.

I'm trying to get the `mean` for "all other" for a given variable.  So, I can use `aggregate` to get the mean of `var`  for each one of the variables in `group` -- yes, the variables are characters and have to be escaped :-(

What I'd like to do is get:

1. the mean for just `-` , and then separately
2. the mean for all other variables (`/ * #`) or not-`-` combined.

So in the example data below, the mean for `-` is 2 and the mean for "all other" is 4.

The real data sets are much longer (1000's of lines), more complex, and variable, so it wouldn't make sense to type the "all other" in separately -- I am thinking something like `~.` would be the way to go.

```
group     var
-         4
-         0
-         2
/         2
/         5
*         3
*         7
*         3
#         4

structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("-", "*", "/"), class = "factor"), var = c(4L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L)), .Names = c("group", "var"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the mean of just the group "-"

```
mean(df[which(df$group=="-"),]$var)
[1] 2
```

This will return the mean of everything other than "-"

```
mean(df[which(df$group!="-"),]$var)
[1] 4
```

And this will return the mean of each group other than "-"

```
df1<-df[which(df$group!="-"),]
ddply(df1,.(group),summarise,mean=mean(var))
  group     mean
1     * 4.333333
2     / 3.500000
3     # 4.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) aggregate.formula** Try this:

```
aggregate(var ~ group, transform(DF, group = ifelse(group == "-", "-", "other")), mean)
```

giving:

```
  group var
1     -   2
2 other   4
```

**2) aggregate.data.frame** or it could be written like this:

```
group <- ifelse(DF$group == "-", "-", "other") 
aggregate(DF["var"], data.frame(group), mean)
```

giving:

```
  group var
1     -   2
2 other   4
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `aggregate(var ~ group == "-", DF, mean)`, but I like the `ifelse` output too. +1